# I get a deprecated warning

Tags: android, api, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I used the code from [Android Hive](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/). Now android studio shows this class uses deprecated api. But don't know which class.
I tried with some classes. My minimum SDK version is 11.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WelcomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int[] layouts;
private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
private PrefManager prefManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(package_name.R.layout.activity_welcome_screen);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(package_name.R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(package_name.R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(package_name.R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(package_name.R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of all welcome sliders
    // add few more layouts if you want
    layouts = new int[]{
            };

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(package_name.R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(package_name.R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, class2.class));
    finish();
}


//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            btnNext.setText(getString(package_name.R.string.start));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            btnNext.setText(getString(package_name.R.string.next));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * Making notification bar transparent
 */
private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}

}
```

This is my WelcomeScreen.java
I am using latest Android Studio
these are in build.gradle
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26

Anyone know how to find this? or is there any debug tool or something with Android Studio??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> private PrefManager prefManager;

PrefManager class has been deprecated. [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager)
If you did not get notified by android studio then just go check the android docs for the classes you used.